# How do you conduct multiple trials in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

In Ruby, you can do something like:

`10.times { puts 'hello world' }`

The best approach that I can come up with in Elixir is:

`Enum.each((0..10), fn(x) -> IO.puts 'hello world' end)`

If run in a program, you get the warning `hello_world.exs:1: warning: variable x is unused`.

**Question: Is there a better way to do this in Elixir?**

Context: I am doing a simulation where 3,000,000 trials need to be conducted. I am not iterating over a list. A simplified scenario would be doing 3,000,000 coin tosses and recording the number of heads.

Comment: For the record, don't try using a zero arg anonymous function for this e.g. `Enum.each 0..10, &(IO.puts "hello world")` - it won't work: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elixir-lang-talk/dV7lReKbKJo/_g5x04B8eGwJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the warning you can use *_* instead of just *x*.

```
Enum.each((0..10), fn(_) -> IO.puts 'hello world' end)
```

And you could probably simplify this by using a list comprehension.

```
for _ <- 0..10,do: IO.puts "hello"
```

`_`  -  This will ignore an argument in function or in pattern matching. If you like you can give a name after underscore.Ex - *_base*

**OTHER CASES**

If someone needs to use the index while running the trail simply specify the variable without _. (like require an index)

For example if someone needed to get squares of the index.

```
for x <- 0..10,do: IO.puts x * x.
```

Comment: Or even just `_`, you don't need to come up with a name for a garbage variable that you are not going to use ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Don't generate a list in such the case, just use a recursion:

```
defmodule M do
  def func(0), do: nil
  def func(n) do
    IO.puts "hello world"
    func(n-1)
  end
end

M.func(10)
```

Or you could implement a Ruby-like way to do the same thing:

```
defmodule RubyHelpers do
  def times(0, _), do: nil
  def times(n, func) do
    func.()
    times(n-1, func)
  end
end

import RubyHelpers
10 |> times(fn -> IO.puts "hello world" end)
```